# Progress Bar updates out of synch with image downloads

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

I have an iPad app where I download a list of images and a progress bar updates as the images are downloaded.  I can't seem to get the progress bar and image downloads to match up.  The progress bar always finishes before the image downloads are completed.  I have a method UpdateProgressBar that should increment the progress bar every time an image is downloaded.

```
-(void)DownloadPhoto{
    NSMutableArray *failedDownloads = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        listPhoto = [CoreDataRead GetPhotoList:[self selectedAccountGuid]];
        dispatch_group_t downloadGroup = dispatch_group_create();
        for (Photo *item in listPhoto) {
            NSString *imageName = item.photoName;
            NSString *myURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://acimagedownload.com/photos/", imageName];
            NSURL        *url       = [NSURL URLWithString:myURL];
            NSURLRequest *request   = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

            dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup);
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

            if (connectionError == nil && data != nil)
            {
                if (data != nil)
                {
                    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",item.guid, @".png"]];

                        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
                        NSLog(@"Photo Downloaded %@!", @"");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"image is not downloaded");
                    }
                }
                else if (connectionError != nil)
                {
                    [failedDownloads addObject:myURL];
                    NSLog(@"Error %@",[connectionError description]);
                }
                else
                {
                    [failedDownloads addObject:myURL];
                    NSLog(@"Image Download Failed %@!", @"");
                }
                dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup);
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self UpdateProgressBar];
                });
            }];
            dispatch_group_wait(downloadGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self DownloadVideo];
        });
    });
}

-(void)UpdateProgressBar{
    currentTask = currentTask + 1;
    NSLog(@"Current Task %@!", [@(currentTask) stringValue]);
    float progressPercentage = (float)currentTask/(float)taskCount;
    [self.progressBar setProgress:progressPercentage animated:YES];
    if(currentTask == taskCount){
        [self ShowDoneAlert];
    }
}
```

Comment: `NSURLConnection` `sendAsynchronousRequest` was deprecated in iOS 9. (In fact just about every part of NSURLConnection was deprecated.) It's not wise to do new development using APIs that were deprecated 2 major OS versions ago. I suggest rewriting your code using `NSURLSession`.

Comment: The code in UpdateProgressBar seems like an appropriate part of this question.

Comment: I added the UpdateProgressBar code.

Comment: I didn't notice that NSURLConnection was deprecated.  Usually the code will be flagged.  It wasn't for some reason.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the `updateProgressBar` method why you get that behaviour but one thing that I noticed is that your `dispatch_group_wait(downloadGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);` is inside your loop.

So what happens is, you go into the first iteration of the loop and at the end of it, the thread execution stops and waits for the first `dispatch_group_leave`. After that is continues to the next iteration and so on.

If this is the desired behaviour (but I doubt it, I think you actually want your downloads to run in parallel) you should probably use a `dispatch_semaphore_t` or even a serial queue.

Comment: I want them to run one after another.  I had them running in parallel and I had issues.

Comment: I found the issue.  The count was incorrect.  Once I corrected the count it started working correctly.

Comment: Any advice on a download strategy?  I can have between 0 to 150 images downloading.   Two at time?  I imagine having 150 threads downloading images at the same time wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: You could divide by ten and have 15 runs of 10 images. I'd do that by creating an outer loop from 0 to 15 and inside a new `dispatch_group` for each iteration. At the end of the outer loop just `dispatch_group_wait`. Also `DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER` is not a very good idea, try to have timeout.

Comment: Forever is just there for testing.  I'll change it once I get everything working correctly.